# как выводить одни и те же элементы разных списков?

Tags: python

У меня есть два списка, и я хочу при помощи модуля random выводить одни и те же элементы. Например, если random.sample() вывел в 1 списке 4 элемент, то и со 2 списка выведет 4 элемент и запишет их рядом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
rand_index=random.randint(0,len(list_1)-1)
print(list_1[rand_inex],list_2[rand_index],sep=' ')
```

P.S. Решение для списков одинаковой длины. Если длина разная, то берите рандом до длины списка с минимальной длиной.(Хотя смысла в такой задаче не много)

P.P.S print будет работать только для третьего питона, для второго нужно будет сделать по классике)

Comment: Понял, спасибо, работает :) А зачем в rand_index=random.randint(0,len(list_1)-1) делать len(list_1)-1? Разве не лучше сделать len(list_1)?

Comment: @Samwise почему-то мне кажется, что там нестрогое условие в рандоме, а так как списки начинаются с нуля, то индекс последнего элемента это длина листа за вычетом единицы

Comment: понял, хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Какой смысл в указании `sep=' '`?. Это же значение по умолчанию.

Comment: @nomnoms12 ну просто потому, что так точнее, плюс есть вероятность, что автору нужно было по-другому выводить

Comment: @rokitoker Точнее? Тогда почему бы не указать ещё `end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False`. Хотя функция `print` и так содержит много логики. _Есть вероятность, что автору нужно будет по-другому выводить_. Может, заменить на нейтральное: `import sys; sys.stdout.write(list_1[rand_inex] + ' ' + list_2[rand_index] + '\n')`? - ... .

Comment: @nomnoms12 вы серьезно хотите об этом поговорить?

Comment: @rokitoker Если Вас всё устраивает, мы можем не продолжать. Это всего лишь мой абсолютно субъективный комментарий. Но вообще тема довольно интересная. Ставлю её в один ряд с `if x == True` и другими возможностями засорить код и впустую потрать время, как своё, так и того, кто это читает. В маленьком примере не существенно, но если так делать во всём коде, мне жалко того, кто это будет поддерживать.